# Change iOS SwiftUI Keyboard Extension Height

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, ios15

*I have seen potential duplicates of this question but none of them seem to have a minimum reproducible example and have small snippets of code that leave out important context. Additionally, since I'm using SwiftUI I'm not sure that many of the answers apply.*

I am using SwiftUI to build an iOS keyboard extension. Here is the relevant code:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let keyboardController = UIHostingController(rootView: KeyboardWrapper())
        keyboardController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        view.addSubview(keyboardController.view)
    }
}

struct KeyboardWrapper: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { rect in
            Keyboard(rect: rect)
        }
    }
}
```

The root of my keyboard extension is at `KeyboardViewController`, which adds as a subview a `UIHostingController` that wraps the root of the SwiftUI views, `KeyboardWrapper`. `KeyboardWrapper` then creates the `Keyboard`. This works as a way to set up a keyboard that has the same height as the system keyboard, as shown here:

[image: system-height keyboard]

My question is *how can I change the height of my keyboard*? I have seen the posts around adding constraints but again they lack sufficient context for me to know exactly where to put them in the code.

Comment: Here is a great tutorial, check it out: https://www.raywenderlich.com/49-custom-keyboard-extensions-getting-started

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to use `anchors`.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let keyboardController = UIHostingController(rootView: KeyboardWrapper())
        keyboardController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(keyboardController.view)
        
        keyboardController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        keyboardController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        keyboardController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        keyboardController.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}

struct KeyboardWrapper: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(" A ") {
                print("A")
            }
            .background(Color.red)
            .foregroundColor(.white)

            Button(" B ") {
                print("B")
            }
            .background(Color.black)
            .foregroundColor(.white)

            Button(" C ") {
                print("C")
            }
            .background(Color.red)
            .foregroundColor(.white)

            Button(" D ") {
                print("D")
            }
            .background(Color.black)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}
```

But I can see that your custom keyboard is embedded in a `GeometryReader`, which can lead to auto layout constraints not working properly. In that case, you can just fix the height by adding this line below the other constraints:

```
keyboardController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a height constraint, and you need to set the priority.

See this snippet:

```
var expandedHeight : CGFloat = 500

var heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute:.height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: expandedHeight)

heightConstraint.priority = .init(999)

myKeyboardView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
```

Place this in the file that is creating the Keyboard view.

Comment: I placed this in `KeyboardViewController.viewDidLoad` and used `keyboardController.view` in place of `myKeyboardView` in the code you pasted. The keyboard now crashes with `"Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint"`

Comment: Sorry, put it in the `viewWillAppear(_animated: Bool)` function. :/